# Issue with Kohana 2.x Cache

Tags: php, caching, kohana, kohana-cache

I'm using Kohana 2.x, I want to implement cache for database results. For that I trying as follows,

```
$cache = Cache::instance();   
$siteSettings = $cache->get('siteSettings');
if ( ! $siteSettings)
{ 
    // for 1st request only it entering, this I've verified    
    $siteSettings = ORM::factory('siteSettings', 1);
    $cache->set('siteSettings', $siteSettings, array('siteSettings'), 0);
}
```

After that if I try to access table columns as

```
$siteSettings->adminEmail;
```

Though it again hitting the database, even it is not entered into above `if` condition. Where I'm doing mistake ? I'm using file cache and sure that folder have writable permissions and I've verified the cache file that it has database results.

Edit:

Following are my cache settings

```
$config['default'] = array(
    'driver' => 'file',
    'params' => APPPATH.'cache',
    'lifetime' => 1800,
    'requests' => -1
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should have

```
// Prevents cached items from being reloaded  
protected $reload_on_wakeup = FALSE;
```

in respective table model class.

Answer (score 0):

Cache doesnt work because you not set `time period`:

```
$cache->set('siteSettings', $siteSettings, array('siteSettings'), 0);
```

You overwrite default setting for time period 3600 seconds ( U set 0). Set time for cache` lifetime.

Comment: I thought time period as zero means for full time until I clear cache myself. Though I've tried time period value as 3600, even for second request it hitting db.

Comment: @Mahesh.D did u check all settings of  cache driver?

Comment: @Mahesh.D and why not $cache->set('siteSettings', $siteSettings); ?

Comment: I've updated my question with cache settings info, please check and thanks for your support.

Comment: @Mahesh.D see prev.question

Comment: Sorry, I haven't get words.

Comment: @Mahesh.D and why not $cache->set('siteSettings', $siteSettings);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45005/discussion-between-mahesh-d-and-voodoo417)

Comment: Thanks for your support, finally I figured it out.

Comment: Finally one thing, even if I cache the table records 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM tbl_name' query is hitting when trying to get records. Any idea ?